# no contents in tkinter url request

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, attributeerror

Hi I am currently adapting a tutorial for a currency converter with a web request fro XE.com and neither the tutorial code or my code seems to work correctly I keep getting this.

CResult.set(a1.contents[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

This is how I have been told to use it from the video.

```
#function that obtain results
def result():
    source_code = requests.get("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=" + str(amount.get()) + "&From=" + str(Cone.get()) + "&To=" + str(Ctwo.get()))
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    a1 = soup.find('td', {'class': 'rightCol'})
    CResult.set(a1.contents[0])
#end 

#varibles that hold user inputs of textboxes
amount = StringVar()
Cone = StringVar()
Ctwo = StringVar()
CResult = StringVar()
#end
```

The program runs fine apart from that although I still have not had an actual result value from XE show up.
Here is the full code. (https://pastebin.com/ZNshGxu5)

Here is my code (https://pastebin.com/BR3xKybN) that I am trying to do, im not really making a converter right now just something that gets the current exchange rate. Later I will put it all in a while loop so the rate 1 and rate 2 data constantly updates.

Like this one I built. (https://pastebin.com/WEnrn6Ku)
All im trying to do is make this python program into a windowed app.

In my code I get the same error.
CResultRate1.set(r1.contents[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

However my program window will not even open or when I can open it it still has the same error?

Im new to Webscraping and tkinter so please excuse me for n00bness I am reading books too but they dont really help to much with debugging.

Comment: Your `soup.find()` call is not finding anything; indeed, when I view source of that page in my browser, there is no reference to a `rightCol` class anywhere.  You really need to check the result before trying to use it.  (There is a `rateCell` class that looks like it might be what you're looking for - could you simply have mistyped it?)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
soup.find('span', 'uccResultAmount').contents
```

Comment: will give them a shot later and vote thanks sometimes i need people to point out the obvious

Comment: now I am getting this soup.find('span', 'uccResultAmount').contents - CResult.set(a1.contents[0])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contents'